# KnockoutJS if statement inside foreach loop

Tags: knockout.js

Here I have this code:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: entries">
    <tr>
        <td><i class="icon-file"></i> <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.goToPath"></a></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

I would like to have something like this (it's pseudocode):

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: entries">
    <tr>
        <td><i class="{{ if type == 'file' }} icon-file {{/if}}{{else}} icon-folder {{/else}}"></i> <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, click: {{ if type == 'file' }} $parent.showFile {{/if}}{{else}} $parent.goToPath {{/else}}"></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Is it possible to write something like this on KnockoutJS?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

One option is to do something like:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: entries">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- ko if: type === 'file' -->
                <i class="icon-file"></i>
                <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.showFile"></a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: type !== 'file' -->
                <i class="icon-folder"></i>
                <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.goToPath"></a>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/9DHHh/

Otherwise, you can simplify your view by moving some logic into your view model like:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: entries">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <i data-bind="attr: { 'class': $parent.getClass($data) }"></i>
            <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.getHandler($data)"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then, add methods on your view model to return the appropriate value:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.entries = [
        { name: "one", type: 'file' },
        { name: "two", type: 'folder' },
        { name: "three", type: 'file'}
    ];

    this.getHandler = function(entry) {
        console.log(entry);
        return entry.type === 'file' ? self.showFile : self.goToPath;
    };

    this.getClass = function(entry) {
        return entry.type === 'file' ? 'icon-file' : 'icon-filder'; 
    };

    this.showFile = function(file) {
        alert("show file: " + file.name);
    };

    this.goToPath = function(path) {
        alert("go to path: " + path.name);
    };
};
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/9DHHh/1/

Comment: http://pastie.org/3334757  It's my code, based on your example. But it doesn't work for me - it generates TDs without content inside.
I use knockout-2.0.0.js

Comment: Can you fork this one?  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/9DHHh/.  I don't see anything wrong from your pastie link.

Comment: It works well without <!-- ko if: type !== 'file' --><!-- /ko --> conditions - it renders a table with no problems, but with conditions it doesn't work.

Comment: Does the original fiddle render properly for you?  What browser are you using?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the containerless control flow syntax, which is based on comment tags:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: entries">
    <tr>
        <!-- ko if: type === "file" -->
            <td><i class="icon-file"></i> <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.showFile"></a></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: type !== "file" -->
            <td><i class="icon-folder"></i> <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.goToPath"></a></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```