# Iterate through indexes of array using knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way to loop through a knockout observableArray's indexes, much like you would with a for loop in a language like C# or Java?

With the code below, I'm just grabbing from the first index ( 0 ) but I want to be able to loop through the indexes and get the values from them as they come

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
             <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: SelectAll" value="0" />
          </th>
          <th>Employee Name</th>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tue</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thu</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Items">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="entity-id" data-bind="if: Timesheets()[0].RowID == 0, checked: IsChecked" />
          </td>
          <td><a class="span8" data-bind="if: Timesheets()[0].RowID == 0, text: EmployeeName, attr: { rowspan: Timesheets()[0].RowSpan }"></a>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" class="span6" data-bind="value: Timesheets()[0].SundayHours"/>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" class="span6" data-bind="value: Timesheets()[0].MondayHours" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="span6" data-bind="value: Timesheets()[0].TuesdayHours"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="span6" data-bind="value: Timesheets()[0].WednesdayHours"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="span6" data-bind="value: Timesheets()[0].ThursdayHours"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="span6" data-bind="value: Timesheets()[0].FridayHours"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="span6" data-bind="value: Timesheets()[0].SaturdayHours"/></td>
        </tr>                          
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way to do this with knockout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest [foreach](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) bindings, using the elementless notation (see "Note 4" on linked documentation) for the second level. Combine that with using `$parent` and `$data` from the [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) and create something like this:

```html
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Items">
    <!-- ko foreach: Timesheets -->
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="entity-id"/></td>
          <!-- ko if: $parent.Timesheets()[0] == $data -->
          <td data-bind="text: $parent.EmployeeName, 
                         attr: { rowspan: $parent.Timesheets().length }"></td>
          <!-- /ko -->
          <td><input data-bind="value: SundayHours"/></td>
          <td><input data-bind="value: MondayHours" /></td>
          <td><input data-bind="value: TuesdayHours"/></td>
          <td><input data-bind="value: WednesdayHours"/></td>
          <td><input data-bind="value: ThursdayHours"/></td>
          <td><input data-bind="value: FridayHours"/></td>
          <td><input data-bind="value: SaturdayHours"/></td>
        </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZTyY/) with a working example. I'm not sure why, but the `if` binding wasn't working properly directly on the `td` element. Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177814/knockoutjs-if-statement-inside-foreach-loop)'s answer I used the `<!-- ko if: ... -->` syntax, which does work.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely a cleaner solution than what I was using before, however the rowspan still isnt working :(. The table isnt expanding the row.

Comment: I've updated my answer, added a link to a working example with rowspan.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely give that a try.

Answer (score 3):

To do this, use the $index context binding. This is gives the 0-based index of the array element.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: ['a','b','c','d','e']">
    <span data-bind="text: $index"></span>
</div>
```

would yield

0
1
2
3
4