# Knockout.js If condition in a for each loop

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a view with `Knockout Js` which has a loop. I need to add an if condition for one of them. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9178123/4761773) but that does not seem to work.

***My code :***

```
<!-- ko foreach: systems -->
<div class="form-group system-status-row border-left border-green">
    <div class="col-sm-2 control-label">
        <label data-bind="text: type"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm status-btns four-btns">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Operational</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Partial</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Non Operational</button>
            <!-- ko if: type !== "Generator" -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse">On Generator</button>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

One of the options in type is Generator but the fourth button is still shown even for that row. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockout needs a () after type to get it working.

```
 <!-- ko if: type() !== "Generator" -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse" >On Generator</button>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Good, You found mistake by yourself.

> There is an easy trick to identify these kind of mistakes,
>   specifically while performing bindings in views.

***Browser Console Logging:***

```
<!-- ko foreach: systems -->
<div class="form-group">
            <!-- ko if: type !== "Generator" -->

                //Logs the Current scope data in browser console:
                //And property data too: 
                <button data-bind="click: function () { console.log($data); console.log(type); }"> Current Data Log </button>

                //You Button Code
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse">On Generator</button>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Just `Click` on the `Current Data Log` Button in the Browser, this will log the current data of the scope in the *browser console window*.

It's really helpful to get to know, whats going with view and data binding.

I hope this will help you!